# Unable to get submenu to display to right of right caret. Displays under instead and cannot be clicked

Tags: html, html-lists, navbar, wiki

Learning over here. Creating a nav bar for my teams Wiki site and having issues with getting the submenu to display to the right of the right caret. The submenu instead shows up at the bottom of the dropdown menu but cannot be clicked on.

Any help is appreciated. My HMTL is below and then the CSS is below that.

```
 <li class="dropdown">
 <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-   expanded="false">For HM's<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
  <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><b>Campus</b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="URL">Intern HM Self Service Portal</a></li>
  <li><a href="URL">Talent Management and Planning</a></li>
  <li><a href="URL">Requisition Management</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="Add URL">Managing an Intern</a></li>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="URL">Intern Mentors Under Resources Tab</a></li>
        </ul>
```

`

```
:root {
    --awsui-grey-100: rgb(250,250,250); /* Oxygen */
    --awsui-grey-200: rgb(234,237,237); /* Chromium */
    --awsui-grey-300: rgb(213,219,219); /* Zinc */
    --awsui-grey-400: rgb(170,183,184); /* Silver */
    --awsui-grey-500: rgb(134,149,150); /* Platinum */
    --awsui-grey-600: rgb(84,91,100);   /* Mercury */
    --awsui-grey-900: rgb(22,25,31);    /* Lead */

    --awsui-orange-500: rgb(236,114,17); /* Copper */
    --awsui-orange-600: rgb(235,95,7); /* Bromine */

    --awsui-blue-500: rgb(0,161,201); /* Argon */
    --awsui-blue-600: rgb(0,125,188); /* Cobalt */

    --awsui-green-500: rgb(106,175,53); /* Fluorine */
    --awsui-green-600: rgb(30,137,0); /* Phosphorous */

    --awsui-squid-ink: rgb(35,47,62); /* Squid Ink */
    --awsui-squid-ink-transparent: rgba(35,47,62,.5); /* Squid Ink half opacity */

    --awsui-amazon-orange: rgb(255,153,0); /* Amazon Orange */
    --awsui-amazon-orange-transparent: rgb(255,153,0,0.5); /* Amazon Orange */

    --base-type: var(--awsui-grey-200);
    --base-header: var(--awsui-grey-100);
    --base-inverted: var(--awsui-grey-900);
}

#sitewide-announcement-banner .hidden-print {
    background: rgb(241, 250, 255)!important;
    border: 1px solid var(--awsui-blue-600)!important;
    color: var(--awsui-grey-900)!important;
    padding: 14px 20px!important;
    margin: 20px 0!important;
}
/*permissions thing, messes with header*/
#xdocPrimaryOwner {display: none;}
.main,
#docextrapanes {
    /* background: var(--awsui-grey-200); */
}

.navbar #nav-links div {
    color: #000000;
}

.navbar ul.nav.navbar-nav li a.icon-navbar:focus,
.navbar ul.nav.navbar-nav li a.icon-navbar:hover {
/*    background-color:#36729e; */
    background-color:#888888;
    outline: initial;
}

.navbar #companylogo, .navbar #nav-create-page, .navbar #nav-search {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#menuview .navbar {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,28,36,.5);
}
#headerglobalsearchinput {
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid var(--awsui-grey-600);
}

/* MISC STUFF */
/* Disabled the edit button because the WYSIWYG destroys content when transcluding the header */
#tmEdit {
    display: none!important;
}

/*Edit buttons override */
.thisIsAPageView > .document-header {
  width: 400px !important;
}

/* Disables a paragraph that gets injected between the header and navigation by the wiki */
.airwolf-header + p {
    display: none;
}

.navbar #nav-create-page {
    display: none;
}

/* TYPOGRAPHY */
body, p, a, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: "Amazon Ember", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body,
#body p,
#body a,
#body li,
#body h1,
#body h2,
#body h3,
#body h4,
#body h5,
#body h6 {
    font-family: "Amazon Ember", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

#body h1,
#body h2,
#body h3,
#body h4,
#body h5,
#body h6 {
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

#body .special {font-size: 44px; line-height: 50px; font-weight: 300;}
#body h1:first-of-type {font-size: 28px; line-height: 40px; margin-top: 0px;} 
#body h1       {font-size: 28px; line-height: 40px; font-weight: 700;}
#body h2       {font-size: 22px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 700;}
#body h3       {font-size: 18px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 700;}
#body h4       {font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;}
#body h5       {font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;}
#body h6       {font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;}


/* WIKI MODS */
/* ========================================================================== */
/* Main content column */
#body #contentcontainer .main {
    padding: 0 20px 20px;
}

.airwolf-header {
    margin: 0 -20px!important;
    width: auto!important;
}

/* Breadcrumbs*/
#hierarchy {
    margin: 0 -20px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: var(--awsui-squid-ink);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
#mainContentArea > .xcontent {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.breadcrumb > li + li:before {color: var(--awsui-grey-300);}
.breadcrumb a {color: var(--awsui-grey-200);}
.breadcrumb > .active:last-of-type a {color: var(--awsui-grey-100);}

/* Document meta */
.xdocLastModification {
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}
.xdocLastModification .wikilink,
#body .xdocLastModification .wikilink a {
    font-size: 10px;
}
.titleDivider {
    display: none;
}
.document-header {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 25;
    top: -38px;
    width: 250px;
    float: right;
}
.document-header .document-menu,
.document-header .document-info {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.document-header .document-menu {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.1;
    transition: .2s opacity ease;
}
.document-header .document-menu:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.document-header .document-info {
    pointer-events: none;
}
#document-title {
    display: none;
}
#document-title h1 {
    background: none;
}
#xwikicontent {
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
}

#xwikicontent,
#docextrapanes {
    /* background: var(--awsui-grey-200); */
}

.btn, input.button {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: var(--awsui-grey-100);
    color: var(--awsui-grey-900);
    border: 1px solid var(--awsui-grey-600);
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 4px 20px;
}

.btn:hover, input.button:hover {
    background-color: var(--awsui-grey-200);
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid var(--awsui-grey-900);
    color: var(--awsui-grey-900);
}

.edit_section {
    overflow: visible;
    top: -11px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: .2s opacity ease;
}
.edit_section:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.edit_section + * {
    clear: both;
}
.wikimodel-emptyline {
    display: block;
}

#footerglobal {
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Limits content to a fake content column */
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .airwolf-header ~ *:not(.navbar-inverse) {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #menuview, #sitewide-announcement-banner {
        display: none;
    }
    .btn-demo {
        display: none;   
    }
    .amazon-wiki-toc {
        display: none;
    }
    .edit_section {
        display: none;
    }
    .document-header {
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        background-color: #121821!important;
        margin: 2px -20px 0 -30px;
        border: none!important;
        padding-left: 50px;
    }
    .dropdown-header {
        color: #aaaaaa!important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-collapse {
        background-color: transparent!important;
    }
}

/************************************
* Airwolf header - stripe animation  
************************************/

.airwolf-header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgb(35,47,62);
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 170px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.airwolf-header::after {
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 240px 240px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    content: '';
    background: red;
    width: 340px;
    height: 340px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.airwolf-header-title {
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: "Amazon Ember", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(250,250,250);
    top: 40px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.airwolf-header-title::after {
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: rgb(255,153,0);
}
.airwolf-header-subtitle {
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: "Amazon Ember", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(250,250,250);
    top: 99px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.airwolf-header-stripe-shine {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    transform: rotate(-70deg);

    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-name: shine;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.airwolf-header-stripe-shine.two {
    height: 10px;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}

.airwolf-header-stripe-fade {
    display: block;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 50px;

    background: rgb(236,114,17);

    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;

    transform: rotate(-20deg);
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-name: fadeInOut;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.airwolf-header-stripe-fade.one {
    background: rgb(255,153,0);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    animation-duration: 6s;
}
.airwolf-header-stripe-fade.two {
    background: rgb(236,114,17);
    margin-bottom: 75px;
    animation-duration: 17s;
}
.airwolf-header-stripe-fade.three {
    background: rgb(236,114,17);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    animation-duration: 7s;
}
.airwolf-header-stripe-fade.four {
    animation-name: fadeInOutDark;
    background: rgb(35,47,62);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    animation-duration: 9s;
}
.airwolf-header-stripe-fade.five {
    background: rgb(255,153,0);
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    animation-duration: 13s;
}

@keyframes shine {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        left: -100%;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    }

    15% {
        transform: rotate(-70deg);
    }

    25% {
        left: 50%;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        left: 150%;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    }
}

#menuview .navbar-brand {
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: block;
    background-size: 100%;

}

#menuview .navbar-brand img {
    display: none;
}

.navbar li.navbar-help-menu > a.dropdown-toggle {
    color: var(--awsui-grey-900);
}

@keyframes fadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 0.9;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInOutDark {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: .5;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

/************************************
* Navbar  
************************************/

li {
 display: block;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}


.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

.navbar-inverse {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    top: -45px;
    background-color: transparent!important;
    background-image: none!important;
    border: none;
    z-index: 2;
}

/* Menu Hover */
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
   color: #fff!important;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

/* Menu Hover */
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:active {
   background: rgb(236,114,17);
   color: #000!important;
}

/* Menu Click After */
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
   background: rgb(236,114,17);
   color: #000!important;
}

.dropdown-menu {
   margin: 2px 0 0 -1px;
}
/* Dropdown Menu Hover */
.dropdown-menu li > a:active,
.dropdown-menu li > a:focus,
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover {
   position: relative;
   background: rgb(236,114,17);
   color: #000!important;
   outline: initial;
}

.dropdown-header {
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #232f3e;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: -5px!important;
}

/* Menu Collapsed Mode */
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
   background: rgb(236,114,17);
   color: #000!important;
   outline: initial;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    padding-left: 5px;
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

li {
 display: block;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

/************************************
* TOC flyout modal
************************************/

.modal.left .modal-dialog,
.modal.right .modal-dialog {
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    width: 320px;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}

.modal.left .modal-content,
.modal.right .modal-content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
    
.modal.left .modal-body,
.modal.right .modal-body {
    padding: 15px 15px 80px;
}

/*Modal fly from left*/
.modal.left.fade .modal-dialog{
    left: -320px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
         -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
            transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
}
   
.modal.left.fade.in .modal-dialog{
    left: 0;
}
        
/* Modal style */
.modal-content {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    top: 201px;
}

.modal-header {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: -30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.modal-body {
    margin-top: -30px;
}

/* TOC button */
.btn-demo {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #232f3e;
    color: #ffffff;
    left: 0!important;
    position: fixed;
    width: 170px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 40%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin-left: -60px;
}

.btn-demo:hover,
.btn-demo:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background: rgb(236,114,17)!important;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: It may help to more clearly specific your underlying Wiki Engine. I see "_...my teams Wiki_" but, I doubt that you mean '[Teams Wki](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-and-use-a-wiki-tab-in-teams-35ec762d-72ec-4d7f-b858-2949f6cb6014)'. I see some '_google wiki_' reference in your CSS but I still can't tell what specific Wiki you are working with.